# Need to expand related products into a full product info block, is this as big a job as I think it is?

Tags: magento2

The site I'm working on requires extended functionality out of related products. As per the screenshot each related product needs to be an individual product details block by itself. Product groups are not an option as all products are configurable. Basically related products need to behave like little self contained product pages of their own.

[image: Mockup of end product]

The more I look at this as a concept the more it looks like something where extending related products won't be able to do this and it will have to be a scratch built extension which is no small task. Am I right? Or am I missing some magic out of the box functionality?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm about/trying to do.